# tab-pane(bootstrap) is not working properly in Mobile/Desktop

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I created a `tab-pane` in my html and it is working fine but I am not getting the output as expected.

> 1. I wanted content of the tab to be filled in 3/4th of the screen ( both in desktop and mobile).

But I am getting as the tab content is occupying only half of the screen. and in mobiles its very horibble.

Pls check the attached images...  [Desktop version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BeqlX.jpg) .[mobile version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jXuzI.jpg)

code here:

```
<div class="container">
  <ul class="nav nav-pills" id="SkillsTab">

    <li class="active">
      <a href="#skill1" role="pill" data-toggle="pill"><i class="fa fa-star-o"></i> Web Designing </a></li>
    <li><a href="#skill2" role="pill" data-toggle="pill"><i class="fa fa-envelope-o"></i>Marketing</a></li>
    <li><a href="#skill3" role="pill" data-toggle="pill"><i class="fa fa-globe"></i>SEO</a></li>
    <li><a href="#skill4" role="pill" data-toggle="pill"><i class="fa fa-magic"></i>Mobile Design</a></li>
    <li><a href="#skill5" role="pill" data-toggle="pill"><i class="fa fa-paint-brush"></i>Graphic Design</a></li>
    <li><a href="#skill6" role="pill" data-toggle="pill"><i class="fa fa-users"></i>Corporate Identity</a></li>

  </ul>

  <div class="tab-content">
    <div class="tab-pane active bounceInRight" id="skill1">
      <h2><i class="fa fa-star-o"></i>Web Designing</h2>
      <p class="text-justify">The Internet is an ever changing environment that demands that you keep up with the latest and greatest communication platforms.
        <br>
        <br>

      </p>
```

Comment: Can you post the full code snippet? You started half way through a `ul` element and cut us off with two open `div` tags.

Comment: This is the starting

`<div class="container">
       <ul class="nav nav-pills"  id="SkillsTab">
     
      <li class="active">`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you posted the rest of your code the answer may be in your HTML structure. You need to wrap your tabs in a `.row` and then some grid element

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            // content here
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Bootstrap uses negative margins and then balances them out as long as the correct HTML structure is used. Read up the [bootstrap grid system](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid).

Comment: i tried this way adding row,col-md-12, col-sm-6, etc but i am getting the same

Comment: anyway thanks for your help... I wil try it again from first and get to you